# Spotify Api Ajax Post request to get token using the 'ajax-request' node package

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, spotify, ajax-request

I'm trying to receive a token from the **Spotify api** to allow me to search the api and such for songs and other information.

On my sever application `index.js` I start by requiring the package:

```
var request = require('ajax-request');
```

Later on I go to request my token:

```
request.post({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        header: {
            Authorization: 'Basic' + <urlEncodedClientIdAndClientSecret>,

        },

        data: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
        }

    }, function(err, res, body) {

    });
```

However if I try and console log this it always returns undefined, is there an issue with how I've laid out my post request or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Did you run this request through Fiddler (windows) or Paw (Mac) and make sure it truly isn't returning something?  I typically use those to make sure my API calls are in fact returning something since I've been known to mess up data returns either by some type of typo or other mistake.

Comment: Can you log the error and see what you get?

Comment: When I log the error it just comes back with null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh....I just looked at your request again....are you missing a space after the "Basic"?  Try this:

```
Authorization: 'Basic ' + <urlEncodedClientIdAndClientSecret>,
```

Comment: I have also tried this, unfortunately I had the same issue